# asp.net MVC open file from folder and view info such as extentsion and contenttype etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

HI there

I know how to get details from a file when i am uploading it, but am unsure how to do this when the file is already on
the server and i wish to get information like size, contentType etc

drawn a blank much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx